# Github actions services mariaDB, integration test fail

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, github-actions

### Background

- Using Github Actions as our deployment tool.
- There are tests that require integration with the database (MariaDB), and they must pass to build.
- Therefore, I set up mariaDB to run as a docker using the services provided by Github Actions Runner.
- I uploaded all the properties, init.sql, etc. that are required during the test process.

### Problem

Even though the mariadb container is running fine(**mariadb service is healthy.**), I get the following error during testing.

```
DatabaseConnectTest > printDBInfo() FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
            Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException at ScriptUtils.java:282
                Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException at ExceptionFactory.java:62
                    Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException at MariaDbSqlException.java:34
                        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException at AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1688
```

After searching, it seems like it's definitely a DB connection problem, but it's not being solved even after changing various settings one by one.

### Config

Below is the DB connection part of the application.properties configuration file used in the test.
The reason why it is `127.0.0.1` is because Github Actions Runners brings up Docker, and the official documentation says to specify it as localhost: or 127.0.0.1:.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/{databaseName}?autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-mariadb-init.sql
```

Below is the mariadb container setup part of the Gtihub Actions workflow.
Since i'm using the root, i did not create a separate MYSQL_USER, but only set the ROOT_PASSWORD.

```
jobs:
  springboot-build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mariadb:
        image: mariadb:latest
        env:
          MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          MARIADB_DATABASE: '{databaseName}'
          MARIADB_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="healthcheck.sh --connect --innodb_initialized" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Verify MariaDB connection
        env:
          PORT: ${{ job.services.mariadb.ports[3306] }}
        run: |
          while ! mysqladmin ping -h"127.0.0.1" -P"$PORT" --silent; do
            sleep 1
          done

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
            java-version: 11
            distribution: 'temurin'
           
           ...
```

Below is a dependency of spring boot 2.7.x build.gradle.

```
/* Database */
    implementation group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.6.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.0'
    /* Log4JDBC */
    testImplementation group: 'org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2', name:'log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1', version: '1.16'
```

Please help me what's going wrong.

1. try changing localhost > 127.0.0.1
2. add MARIADB_ROOT_HOST: "%"
3. Add `- name: Verify MariaDB connection` step
4. try using tools provided by market place instead of github services

Comment: Given the error is `SQLSyntaxErrorException` i'd assume a syntax error. What is the SQL being executed?

Comment: @danblack `schema-mariadb-init.sql` to create tables and `data.sql` to insert mockup data to reduce the redundancy of adding rows within the test class.

Here's my progress so far

1. renaming the file shcema-{database}-init.sql as the server doesn't seem to recognise it.
2. changed mariadb default character set utf8mb3 > utf8mb4
3. unsetting case sensitivity of table names.

Giving the `-i` option to see the detailed logs during the build process is helping a lot. I'll add a comment when the issue is resolved, thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`? If so there's no explicit database handing in the import. For database configuration files if used, on windows, ensure the file or volume permissions are readonly.